# How does one bind a PrimeNg table with values from 2 different arrays?

Tags: angular, primeng-datatable

I have a PrimeNg table where I display data from a view model object 'reminders'. This object has some fields, one of which (called 'description') has a string of html text (it's value comes from a Tiny MCE editor). My goal is to clean that field of html markup, but merely for display purposes. I must not alter this value on the view model, for it would be saved as such.

My idea was to supply the PrimeNg table with 2 sources of data, one being the 'reminders' object, the other being a view model variable where I would capture and clean the 'description' field and feed it to the table, but I am not aware if it's possible nor what syntax to use. Note that I am using reactive forms in Angular 14. Thanks in advance for any help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

The PrimeNG table accepts *one* array of data. If you have two arrays, you can concatenate them on the fly to generate the one array you need to feed to the table component. But in your particular case, I don't see what's the issue. All you need to do, is add one extra field in your data, e.g. `cleanDescription` and show *that* on the table, instead of the original `description` field. Every time you load your data (assuming you load them from some back-end API), you map your original array to a new array with the added field.